# Why does Maple fail to find a solution to this system of differential equations using rkf45 numerical method but not using the classical method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

Consider the system of differential equations

$$y'(x)=z(x)\cdot g(x)$$
$$z'(x)=y(x)\cdot g(x)$$

where $g(x)$ is just some random number, generated from seed $x$.

How do we solve this system using the *rkf45* numerical method?

Using the "classical" method seems to work just fine, with a plot at the end. Using *rkf45*, there is always a warning that solutions could not be found to the left/right of some particular value.

Here is the code representing this situation.

```
with(Statistics);
with(plots);
with(RandomTools[MersenneTwister]);
gen := proc(t) local hrand, intSeed; setState(t); hrand := Sample('Uniform'(1, 2)); return hrand(1)[1]; end proc;
test := proc() local sys, fcns, p; sys := diff(y(x), x) = z(x)*'gen(x)', diff(z(x), x) = y(x)*'gen(x)'; fcns := {y(x), z(x)}; p := dsolve({y(0) = 0, z(0) = 1, sys}, fcns, type = numeric, method = rkf45); odeplot(p, [[x, y(x)], [x, z(x)]], -4 .. 4, symbol = box); end proc;
test();
```

The code above can be copied and pasted to a Maple worksheet and it will have nicer formatting.

It tries to solve the system of DE with *rkf45.*

Comment: This system of equations has closed form solution.

Comment: @NN2 This system of equations is contrived to be simple enough to get at the question at hand about the use of dsolve. The issue actually arises in a physics research problem that includes a system that doesn't have a closed form solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classical` methods of Maple's `dsolve,numeric` don't do much (if any) adaptive error control.

That's in contrast to the `method=rkf45` solver.

Given the random aspect of the rhs driving functions, how would you want error control (if any) to take effect?

Suppose the solver halves the stepsize temporarily (possibly recomputing over a short duration of the independent variable), to try and assess the error. How should the solver compare such results, in light of the fact that the driver input has a random component?